# Why callback function doesn't work in $scope? Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Why function `getPrice('Table')` doesn't work in controller? It return undefined instead 400. That quite works in plain JS (without `$scope`).

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {   

$scope.prices = [{
    name: 'Bed',
    price: 900
}, {
    name: 'Table',
    price: 400
}];


$scope.getPrice = function (name) {
    $scope.prices.forEach(
    function (el) {
        if (el.name == name) {
            return el.price;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    );
}
};
```

Comment: $scope.getPrice has no return statement, so it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getPrice function does not return anything. Try this one :

```
 $scope.getPrice = function (name) {
             $price = null;
             $scope.prices.forEach(
                     function (el) {
                         if (el.name == name) {
                             $price =  el.price;
                             return;
                         } else {
                             return;
                         }
                     }
             );
             return $price;
         }
```